# Only a product can't save Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have 1 problem with Magento 2.3.3

All products save fine, but only 1 item XYZ cannot save.

I have seen in `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product => function execute()`, `$product->save();` don't work for this product

It show this error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `cp_table`.`type_id` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cp_table` ON main_table.product_id = cp_table.entity_id WHERE (`main_table`.`website_id` = '0') AND (`main_table`.`product_id` IN())
```

Please help me <3 Thanks all, happy coding

Comment: Did you fix the issue?